# Compare the approximation with the actual value of $\Delta w$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Let $w=x^2y+z$

Use differentials to approximate $\Delta w$ as $(x,y,z)$ moves from $(1,2,1)$ to $(1.01, 1.98, 1.03)$

Compare your approximation with the actual value of $Delta w$

---

I calculated $dw=2xydx+ x^2dy+dz$

From there, how to calculate $\Delta w$ ? And how to compare?

Please show me how to calculate step by step. Please write this clearly with formulas. Do not just give the result. Thank you.

Comment: Why close? I will immediately correct if I have a mistake.

Comment: Your $dw$ is not correct. How did you arrive at that?

Comment: Sorry I forget to write 'y' @Raskolnikov

Comment: Please show me the solution @Raskolnikov

Comment: You're right, a $y$ is missing. But then you should have $\nabla w$, it's just the factors in front of $dx$,$dy$ and $dz$ put in a vector.

Comment: By the way, I think what is meant in the question is not $\nabla w$ but $\Delta w$. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Aow yeah! That you said şs true. But I dont know how to write this symbol? Please can you correct this? @Raskolnikov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean a linear approximation for the function $w$. But since you computed the differential $dw$, it is easy to compute an approximation for $\Delta w$ as follows:

$$\Delta w \approx 2xy \Delta x+ x^2 \Delta y+ \Delta z$$

in which

$$(\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z)= (1.01, 1.98, 1.03)-(1,2,1)=(0.01,-0.02,0.03)$$

and

$$(x,y,z)=(1,2,1) \; .$$

Comment: Okay got it! Thank you so much:)

Comment: I dont know this formula. I have learnt it:)